# How is Vishnu remote controlled by Devi Bhagavati?

Tags: vishnu, devi, devi-bhagavata-purana

From *Essence of Devi Bhagavata Purana* hosted on kamakoti website:

http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/devibhagvatpurana2.html

Maha Vishnu remote-controlled by Devi Bhagavati:

> In the Introductory Recitation of  Devi Bhagavatam, Sage Suta quoted Narada Maharshi as having confirmed by Lord Vishnu Himself to Lord Brahma  that His own  Premordial Energy of Universal Existence is the result of  Her empowerment to Maha Vishnu to execute Her commands! Maha Vishnu reiterated that He is subservient to Devi Bhagavati and is always in Her Tapasya or meditation, but at the same time, enjoys freedom to possess the company of Goddess Lakshmi, to incarnate Himself in various forms and features some times as Dasavataras as Fish, Tortoise, Boar, Man-Lion, Dwarf, Rama, Parasurama, Krishna, Buddha or Kalki; some times as Mohini to distribute ‘Amrit’ or Nectar and so on. But His actions are always remote-controlled and are oriented to protect the Virtuous and punish the Wicked. Thus Maha Vishnu is indeed the Highest Representative of Maha Devi with full freedom to act on His own, within the framework of Her Supreme Control.

Can someone produce the relevant passages from Devi Bhagavatam? How can one be remote controlled and at the same time have full freedom? That seems contradictory.

Comment: If Devi is all-pervading, how can it be called as remote-controlling?

Comment: @LazyLubber I think Bhagavati is a deity and stays in her planet. She is all pervading but may be in a different way. So a deity can remote control another deity.

Comment: What you think should not be important here.All pervading has no question or need of remote control.

Comment: @commonman what I think doesn't matter, it is not mine. it is from scripture.

Comment: Remote control is not a sanskrit word,I think there is some mistake in translation.Please check the original.

Comment: @commonman remote control is an English word.